# Sorted dataframe returns data in unordered way while joining the two dataframes

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have two dataframes `players` and `striker_details`. The `striker_details` df is sorted by striker_grade and looks like this:

```
+-------------+-------------+
|player_api_id|striker_grade|
+-------------+-------------+
|        20276|        89.25|
|        37412|         89.0|
|        38817|        88.75|
|        32118|        88.25|
|        31921|         87.0|
+-------------+-------------+
```

The other dataframe `players` is an unordered dataframe and looks like this:

```
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
| id|player_api_id|       player_name|player_fifa_api_id|           birthday|height|weight|
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|  1|       505942|Aaron Appindangoye|            218353|1992-02-29 00:00:00|182.88|   187|
|  2|       155782|   Aaron Cresswell|            189615|1989-12-15 00:00:00|170.18|   146|
|  3|       162549|       Aaron Doran|            186170|1991-05-13 00:00:00|170.18|   163|
|  4|        30572|     Aaron Galindo|            140161|1982-05-08 00:00:00|182.88|   198|
|  5|        23780|      Aaron Hughes|             17725|1979-11-08 00:00:00|182.88|   154|
+---+-------------+------------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
```

When I am trying to join the two dataframes using pyspark join, it is returning an unordered data:

```
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|player_api_id|    striker_grade|       player_name|           birthday|height|weight|
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
|       309726|75.38888888888889|    Andrea Belotti|1993-12-20 00:00:00|180.34|   159|
|        38433|          72.5625|      Borja Valero|1985-01-12 00:00:00|175.26|   161|
|        41157|             82.0|Giovani dos Santos|1989-05-11 00:00:00|175.26|   163|
|        40740|           70.375|      Jeremy Morel|1984-04-02 00:00:00|172.72|   157|
|       109653|             73.5|     John Goossens|1988-07-25 00:00:00|175.26|   150|
+-------------+-----------------+------------------+-------------------+------+------+
```

I used the command: `ss = striker_details.join(players, ["player_api_id"], "inner")`

How can I achieve sorted data?

Comment: If `ss` is a datafame please try `ss.sort_values(by=["column_name"])`. Column name can be something like `striker_grade`.

Comment: @berkeeb yes, `ss` is a dataframe. I tried as you mentioned, but it returned `'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'sort_values'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try chaining `orderBy('striker_grade,ascending=False)` at the end of your `join`:

```
ss = striker_details.join(players, ["player_api_id"], "inner").orderBy('striker_grade',ascending=False)

ss.display()
```

Also, the default join is `inner`, so you don't need to specify it. It is good to show it for explicitness though.

Comment: Thanks for the solution, actually I was going through a pluralsight course on spark and there, the instructor didn't used the chaining part that you had mentioned and still got the output in the descending order, so I thought maybe I was missing some part. Thanks for the help.